# How should be prometheus labels properly used using Java?

Tags: java, prometheus

How should be prometheus labels properly used using Java?

I have Java app, with Spring, but without SpringBoot.

I have a metric, which can be only incremented: I need to count how much time each user have logged in to my system. Users can be added dynamically: like, at the beggining there can be one user, and at the end of the day +40 users. As I understand it, the best way is to make a Counter with labels.

I saw something similar in rabbitmq metrics:

```
# TYPE rabbitmq_queue_message_bytes_persistent gauge
rabbitmq_queue_message_bytes_persistent{durable="true",policy="",queue="ERROR",vhost="/"} 0
rabbitmq_queue_message_bytes_persistent{durable="true",policy="",queue="OK",vhost="/"} 1
rabbitmq_queue_message_bytes_persistent{durable="true",policy="",queue="PROGRESS",vhost="/"} 7
```

So, in my case it should be something like

```
# TYPE user_logins counter
user_logins_total{user="Alex"} 0
user_logins_total{user="Kate"} 1
user_logins_total{user="Ali"} 7
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
private Counter getByLabel(String labelName) {
    Counter counter = map.get(labelName);
    if (counter == null) {
        counter = Counter.build()
                .namespace(NAMESPACE)
                .labelNames(labelName)
                .name(USER_LOGINS_NAME)
                .help(USER_LOGINS_HELP)
                .register();
        map.put(labelName, counter);
    }
    return counter;
}

//With such increment() I receive NPE 
public void increment(String labelName) {
    this.getByLabel(labelName).inc();
}

//With such increment() I receive an error abt I have the counter with the same name each time i try to increment counter more then once. 
public void increment(String labelName) {
    this.getByLabel(labelName).labels(labelName).inc();
}
```

Prometheus client I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_httpserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You usually want to keep the cardinality of your labels low. Each label combination creates a new time series. If you have 40 users, that's at least 40 time series. 40 is not a lot yet, but since you mentioned "users will be added automatically", this sounds pretty bad. (Not an answer to your problem, just a heads-up)

Comment: And just double checking: the counters will reset when the application restarts. Is that okay? Or are you better off with a counter in e.g. Redis?

Comment: It is ok for a counter to reset when the application restarts. See https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get two of the documentation examples running on your side. If it works in plain java, it also works in spring, JEE or elsewhere.

https://github.com/prometheus/client_java

- Example 1: Counter
- Example 2: Labels